# Refactoring mocking code into another class causes Spock tests to fail

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a Groovy/Spock unit test as follows:

```
public class ThingUnitTest extends Specification {

  def "doing a thing delegates to the context"() {
    given : def thing = createThing()
    when  : thing.doThing()
    then  : 1 * thing.context.doThing()
  }

  def createThing() {
    def thing = new ThingImpl()
    thing.context = createThingContext()
    return thing
  }

  def createThingContext() {
    def context = Spy(ThingContext)
    context.foo = Mock(Foo)
    context.bar = Mock(Bar)
    return context
  }
}
```

This test will run without problems. However it turns out that I have other tests that need a `ThingContext`, so I want to move the `createThingContext` code into a common class:

```
public class ThingContextFactory extends Specification {
  def createThingContext() {
    def context = Spy(ThingContext)
    context.foo = Mock(Foo)
    context.bar = Mock(Bar)
    return context
  }
}
```

and then write my unit tests as follows:

```
public class ThingUnitTest extends Specification {
  ...
  def createThingContext() {
    return new ThingContextFactory().createThingContext()
  }
}
```

But now the test fails, with the assertion `1 * thing.context.doThing()` failing with zero interactions.

I also tried the following:

```
public class ThingContextFactory {
  def createThingContext() {
    def mocking = new MockingApi()
    def context = mocking.Spy(ThingContext)
    context.foo = mocking.Mock(Foo)
    context.bar = mocking.Mock(Bar)
    return context
  }
```

But now the tests fail with `MockingApi.invalidMockCreation ... InvalidSpec`

Note that I do not want to use inheritance here, but move common mocking code into helper classes. But when I do this my spock tests fail.

Is there some proper way to refactor Spock mocking code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Spock 0.7, mock objects can only be created in the test class that uses them, or a superclass thereof. This might change in the next version.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Guess I need to move the common code into a base class (sometimes this is a good thing, sometimes not). +1 on relaxing this restriction in a future version.

Comment: I tried to create the mocks in a Trait, which also doesn't seem to work. Is it the same answer for Traits or can it be made to work?

Comment: It looks like there are still no possibilities to do it in newer 2.3 version?
Or there is a way around?